# % setting in top doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the following code in % way to set up the position, in case of different screen width.

```css
.text {
  padding:10%;
 }

.title {
 font-family: 'Great Vibes',cursive;
 font-size:150%;
 position:relative;
 border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(248,221,225,0.7);
 top:-10px;
 left:0;
    width:70%
}

.title p {
 position:relative;
 top:40px;
 left:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<div class="title"> 
 <p> title title title title title </p>
</div>
 </div>
```

So, I change the setting on top, and left:

```css
.text {
  padding:10%;
 }

.title {
 font-family: 'Great Vibes',cursive;
 font-size:150%;
 position:relative;
 border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(248,221,225,0.7);
 top:-8%;
 left:0;
}

.title p {
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 left:-8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
   <div class="title"> 
    <p> title title title title title </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

But, no matter how much I changed on .title p's top, its position doesn't change.

Anyone knows why? and How to change that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot/mockup of the desired result?

Comment: @Chris it's the first snippet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give parent element a `height`

```css
.text {
  padding:10%;
 }

.title {
 font-family: 'Great Vibes',cursive;
 font-size:150%;
 position:relative;
 border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(248,221,225,0.7);
 top:-8%;
    height:50px;
 left:0;
}

.title p {
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 left:-4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
   <div class="title"> 
    <p> title title title title title </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I  just added "margin" before top and it's working.

```
.title p {
position:relative;
margin-top:50%;
left:-8%;
}
```

Comment: thx!! do you know why there is such a difference,since I have already set the position:relative?

Comment: Er..actually, it doesn't work for me:( the border will still move with the title txt.  I am testing using firefox.

Comment: Yes you are right. So, to be clear. You want your text (let's say half of it) to be on top of the border. Correct? you are using the border as a background. Is that what you want the result to be?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact effect I want.